# How can I make the options in the menu stack in front of the options from the Contact Form 7 field

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I tried to fix the problem by setting the menu z-index to 10 and the form z-index to 9 but I still get the issue.

[image]

Comment: _"The picture basicly says it all."_ - it might show what the _problem_ is, but it doesn't give us anything to actually _debug_. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), instead present a proper [mre] of the issue directly inside the question.

Comment: Can you share your site link?

Comment: @Earid yes it's https://cyberfinance.co.za/contact/